# Can't install libglib2.0-dev

Tags: 11.10, aptitude, glib

Since [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) can't be installed in Oneiric, I decided to try and build it from source instead. The build is interrupted because it complains glib is not installed, so I thought I better install the glib development package. But I cant:

```
$ sudo aptitude install -V libglib2.0-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libglib2.0-dev{b} [2.30.0-0ubuntu4]  
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1 775 kB of archives. After unpacking 8 831 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libglib2.0-dev: Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.30.0-0ubuntu4) but 2.31.0-0ubuntu1~oneiric1 is installed.
                  Depends: libglib2.0-bin (= 2.30.0-0ubuntu4) but 2.31.0-0ubuntu1~oneiric1 is installed.
Internal error: the solver Install(libglib2.0-bin 2.30.0-0ubuntu4 <libglib2.0-dev 2.30.0-0ubuntu4 -> {libglib2.0-bin 2.30.0-0ubuntu4 libglib2.0-bin 2.30.0-0ubuntu4}>) of a supposedly unresolved dependency is already installed in step 237
```

Aptitude the suggest a solution that involves removing basically all libraries, including libc.

How do I install the glib development package?

**Edit**

```
$ apt-cache policy libglib2.0-0
libglib2.0-0:
  Installed: 2.31.0-0ubuntu1~oneiric1
  Candidate: 2.31.0-0ubuntu1~oneiric1
  Version table:
 *** 2.31.0-0ubuntu1~oneiric1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.30.0-0ubuntu4 0
        500 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Can you add what PPAs you've added to your system to your question? Looks like you added something that has newer versions of libglib2.0

Comment: Please post the output of `apt-cache policy libglib2.0-0`

Comment: @FlorianDiesch Updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are/have used the "Gnome 3 PPA" which on 11/07 removed the Oneiric glib packages, why I didn't purse.

Sorta leaves you in a touchy situation, don't know if 11.10 has any plans to upgrade glib to 2.31

The packages are still available for manually downloading & installing, links here under 
"Builds" section, if so just grab the libglib2.0-dev_2.31.0-0ubuntu1~oneiric1 package

https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3/+sourcepub/2031687/+listing-archive-extra

Your other option could be to use ppa-purge & return to 11.10 versions, not sure how well that would go.

Answer (score 0):

Oneiric was the first release to enable "mutliarch" (more information in the [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OneiricOcelot/ReleaseNotes#A32-bit_compatibility_on_amd64_systems)) on default amd64 installations, making it possible to install packages with a foreign architecture - specifically i386 (or 32-bit) packages on amd64 (64-bit). This is primarily being used currently for supporting 3rd-party software like Flash and Skype.

However, `aptitude` was not updated to support multiarch, so if you have any foreign architecture packages installed (which you would if you've installed Flash), aptitude tends to get confused by the state of t